# Binding model from a view wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, model, viewmodel, model-binding

I'm trying to build a DTO to store the software configuration, but I'm stuck because my view is not sending the data to my ViewModel and also to my DTO.
I need to transfer 2 textbox and 3 combobox to my DTO, but using this code the values are always empty.

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModelProcessamentoArquivo : ViewModelBase
{
private PesquisaConfiguracao pesquisaConfiguracao;

public PesquisaConfiguracao PesquisaConfiguracao
        {
            get { return pesquisaConfiguracao; }
            set
            {
                pesquisaConfiguracao = value;

                base.OnPropertyChanged("PesquisaConfiguracao");
            }
        }
}
```

**My DTO/Model**

```
public class PesquisaConfiguracao
    {
        public string ArquivoOrigem { get; set; }
        public string ArquivoDestino { get; set; }
        public string TipoPesquisa { get; set; }
        public string PesquisaVeicular { get; set; }
        public string PesquisaCrediticia { get; set; }
    }
```

**And my View is like this.**

```
<TextBox Name="txtBuscarArquivoOrigem" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="30" Margin="10, 0" Text="{Binding PesquisaConfiguracao.ArquivoOrigem}" />

<TextBox  x:Name="txtBuscarArquivoDestino" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="30" Margin="10, 0" Text="{Binding PesquisaConfiguracao.ArquivoDestino}" IsEnabled="false" />

...
```

Do you guys know why it's happening? I've used something similar in my other project and worked just fine. Also if you have any other possibly way to fix this issue, please comment!

Comment: Was `PesquisaConfiguracao` ever initialized?

Comment: I think you to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on PesquisaConfiguracao

Comment: @EdPlunkett agreed.. May pesquisaConfiguracao = new PesquisaConfiguracao().

Comment: It's initialized in the "ViewModel" constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged, that way the target (view) will update your source object on every change:

```
   <TextBox Name="txtBuscarArquivoOrigem"  Height="30" Text="{Binding PesquisaConfiguracao.ArquivoOrigem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Then implement in your source object the INotifyPropertyChange Interface on it's properties in order to update the view when the value has changed:

```
  private string _arquivoOrigem;

    public string ArquivoOrigem
    {
        get
        {
            return _arquivoOrigem;
        }
        set
        {
            _arquivoOrigem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ArquivoOrigem");
        }
    }
```

Put a BreakPoint in the property setter and it will break there when you change the value in the view TextBox.

If it doesn't work for you probably forgot to set your DataContext to your ViewModel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
```

Or did not initialize your source object:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        pesquisaConfiguracao = new PesquisaConfiguracao
        {
            ArquivoDestino = "aaa",
            ArquivoOrigem = "bbb",
            PesquisaCrediticia = "ccc",
            PesquisaVeicular = "dddd",
            TipoPesquisa = "eee"
        };
    }
```